# Is there any function in SQL to get a random number in a given interval?

Tags: sql

I need to populate a database with random values between 50000 and 15000000 in SQL, someone know any function to do that?

Thanks

Comment: What database system are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which database are you using?

Here's how I'd do it on MS SQL Server, using the [`RAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx) function:

```
DECLARE @MinValue INT
SET @MinValue = 50000

DECLARE @MaxValue INT
SET @MaxValue = 15000000

SELECT @MinValue + CAST(RAND() * (@MaxValue - @MinValue) AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

check these URL [sql-server-random-number-generator-script-sql-query](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/29/sql-server-random-number-generator-script-sql-query/) for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Different DBMSes provide different methods, such as [RAND()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) on MySQL and [DBMS_RANDOM](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#i998740) on Oracle.

What DBMS are you using?